# Prove family of measures $\{\rho_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is tight

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\delta > 0$ and let $\{X_{nk}\mid n \in \mathbb{N}, k \leq n \}$ denote a triangular array of real random variables. Let $\{\rho_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a family of measures defined for $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ as
$$
\rho_n(A) = \int_A \delta^{-2} \sum_{k=1}^n g(x) P_{X_{nk}}(dx)
$$
where $g$ is a non-negative, continuous function. We assume that
$$
\sup_{n} \sum_{k=1}^n E[\vert g(X_{nk}) \vert] < \infty.
$$

I want to show that $\{\rho_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is tight i.e. $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists M \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\sup_n\rho_n(M^c) \leq \epsilon.$

**Thoughts:** I was thinking that maybe Markov's inequality could be used - the fact that
$$
\sup_n P(\vert X_{nk} \vert > N) \leq \frac{1}{N} \sup_n E[\vert X_{nk}  \vert] \to 0
$$
for $N \to \infty$. However I can't quite make it work. How can I show this?

Comment: Is $g$ nonnegative or are you perhaps missing an absolute value in the integrability condition?

Comment: Yes my mistake, I have added it now

Comment: Your idea is exactly right, except that the term on the right should of course go to $0$ as $n\to \infty$ (estimating probabilities by $\infty$ is rarely helpful). Maybe you can post your attempts as an answer and explain where you have doubts?

Comment: What puzzles me is how to turn it into a probability measure I can use this on, $\rho_n$ is just a finite measure. Say I let $\epsilon>0$. Then I need $ \sup_n \rho_n(M^c) = \dots \leq \epsilon$ by converting it into a proability and use the above bound. Also I have corrected it to 0 as you mentioned :)

Comment: I just realized that if you want your $\rho_n$ to be a measure, $g$ needs to be nonnegative anyway. Or are the $\rho_n$ supposed to be signed measures?

Comment: Yes g is non-negative (unimportant to the question itself, but $g(x) = (x - E[X_{X_nk}])^2$)